# How to pass URL parameters into a 3rd party embedded form

Tags: forms, url-parameters

I have my Calendly appointment booking calendar embedded inline on my website.  I need to pass parameters (name, email, phone) into the form via the URL.  When I could just link directly to the Calendly appointment (not having it embedded on the website), I could just add the parameters into the URL and it would automatically prefill the form fields: http://www.calendly.com?firstName=first&lastName=last&email=email&a2=phone.  But now that I have to have it embedded on this website, putting the parameters at the end of the url http://www.mywebsite.com?firstName=first&lastName=last&email=email&a2=phone it does not fill the fields on the embedded form.
Is there a way that I can pull the parameters into the fields via adding something to the embed code?
Here's the embed code:

```js
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/[my meeting link]" style="min-width:320px;height:630px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: You need to add these parameters to the `data-url` attribute of the `div` that will contain the embedded Calendly page, not to your host webpage. Although you can certainly have them in both places if you need to. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66749644/calendly-not-pre-filling-a-form-in-webflow/66753589#66753589

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calendly not pre-filling a form in Webflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66749644/calendly-not-pre-filling-a-form-in-webflow)