# Calendly not pre-filling a form in Webflow

Tags: forms, webflow, calendly

I’m using Calendly in my Webflow project, and it works.
However, I would love to pre-fill the form in Calendly, and there is a guide to do so here: https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/226766767-Pre-populate-invitee-information-on-the-scheduling-page
I’ve managed to make the url look like this, using custom code:

```
mywebsite.com/book-meeting?name=MyFirstname%20MyLastname&email=myemail@test.com
```

But for some reason Calendly is not pre-filling the form.
Is there anyone else, who has tried this and made it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me look you would like to pass custom pre-fill values to your embedded Calendly Link.

The best way to do this is to use Calendly’s Advanced Embed Options: https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020052833-Advanced-embed-options#4

In order to do this you will need to supply your pre-filled values like Name and Email directly to specific Calendly link being embedded. In your example: `mywebsite.com/book-meeting?name=MyFirstname%20MyLastname&email=myemail@test.com`, it looks like you are  passing the pre-fill values to the entire page address rather than specifically to the calendly.com/… scheduling link found in the embedded script.

The best way to do this is as described in help article referenced above. You can add pre fill values script like so:

```
prefill: {
    name:
    email:
    customAnswers:
}
```

so that the script to embed Calendly would look something like:

```
<script>
    const params = (new  URL(window.location)).searchParams

    Calendly.initInlineWidget({
        url: 'https://calendly.com/YOUR_LINK/30min',
        prefill: {
            name: params.get('name'),
            email: params.get('email')
        }         
    });
</script>
```

Where we are taking the parameters from the page url and passing them to Calendly embedded widget. (Note: in this example, I am using an Inline Widget but you can replace this portion of the script with the appropriate API method, ie. `Calendly.initBadgeWidget` or `Calendly.initPopupWidget`)

Hope this helps, happy scheduling!

Comment: Also, fyi, the URL API to parse query parameters is not supported in IE11 https://caniuse.com/?search=url. You'll have to import a polyfill or write a custom parsing function if you need support for that.

Comment: Thank you, I think it might work. I can't really tell though, because now I get an error message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendly is not defined" when I inspect my page. I'm guessing I need to define Calendly somehow in the script, but I am having troubles understanding how. I also can't seem to find it on Calendly's website or the link you sent me.
Do you know how I can define it?